# How to determine measure from the integral equation?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\{c_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}\subset \mathbb C$  and $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |c_{n}| < \infty$ (that is, the series $\sum c_{n}$ is absolutely  converges); we define $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ such that  $F(y)= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}( c_{n}\cdot e^{iny})$, $(y\in \mathbb R).$

Suppose there exists bounded complex [Borel measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_measure) on $\mathbb R$ such that
$$F(y)= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-iyx} d\mu(x);  \  (y\in \mathbb R).$$

**My Questions**:

> (1) What can we say about $\mu$ ? 
>   (2) Can we expect to determine $\mu$  just from the above information; or we need to have some more information to determine $\mu$ ?  Can you suggests some method to determine $\mu$ in such a situation ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Observation.** Given the representation of $F$ as a Fourier series, a candidate for $\mu$ is
$$
\tilde\mu=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}c_k\delta_k,
$$
where $\delta_k$ is the unit Dirac mass at $k$. Clearly
$$
F(y)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}c_k\,\mathrm{e}^{ikx}=
\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}c_k\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm{e}^{ixy}\,d\delta_k(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm{e}^{ixy}\,d\tilde\mu(x).
$$

How did I guess that? Simply by considering initially that $F(y)=\mathrm{e}^{kyi}$.

Now we need to show that $\mu=\tilde \mu$. Let $\nu=\mu-\tilde \mu$. Then
$$
0=F(y)-F(y)=\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm{e}^{ixy}\,d\mu(x)-\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm{e}^{ixy}\,d\tilde\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm{e}^{ixy}\,d\nu(x), \quad \text{for all $y\in\mathbb R.$}
$$
But this implies that $\nu=0$.

Comment: @YSS;  your answer is beautiful; thanks a lot; -\).

Comment: @YSS; thanks once again; and may be this is bit late; Please would you tell me; how one can interchange sum and integral, I mean, $ \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} c_{k} \int_{\mathbb R} e^{ixy} d\delta_{k}(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{ixy} d\tilde{\mu} (x)$ ?; thanks a lot;

Comment: If $\tilde\mu=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}c_k\delta_k$, thetn $\tilde\mu$ is a complex Borel measure, and its total variation is $\|\tilde\mu\|=\sum\lvert c_k\rvert<\infty$. This fact, allows interchanging integral and sum.

Comment: "If $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is measure space; $f_{n}: X\to \mathbb C$; and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{X} |f_{n}| d\mu < \infty$, then $\int_{X} f d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{X} f_{n} d\mu.$" This I read from the book. So, am I suppose to use theorem like this; or am I missing some thing; thanks